# Selecting from top 10 after selection was made

Tags: sql

So I'm writing a query that gets the top 10 counts from my table and shows the total. What I want is for it to split it up on say "Failed" and "Success".

So my Table shows

```
Total   Groups
58  Group 5
32  Group 77
32  Group 78
31  Group 99
29  Group 89
29  Group 34
26  Group 57
15  Group 54
12  Group 25
11  Group 15
```

So if you see in group 5 there is a total of 58 Records. But out of those 58 there is 53 that are "Success" and 5 that are "Failed"

I can't search for Failed accounts and do a top 10 because then the count will be lower and the top 10 will be different.

```
SELECT top 10 Count(distinct FileID) AS Total, Groups
FROM Table
where Date = '2020-05-28'
group by Group
order by Total DESC
```

That's my query. I would like it to show the total count that I showed and then two more columns that have the Success Count and the Fail Count. I can't figure out how to do that part.

So It should look like

```
Failed Success Total   Groups
53       5     58      Group 5
5        27    32      Group 77
```

If I do the query like this it gives me a diffrent top 10 because the counts are low on the Failed or Success.

```
 SELECT top 10 Count(distinct FileID) AS Total, Groups
    FROM Table
    where Date = '2020-05-28' AND Status = 'Success'
    group by Group
    order by Total DESC
```

Here is my Query that I get SUPER close, but either the Totals Double gives a higher number that it should. Only records that have nothin in them are correct.

```
SELECT top 10 Count(distinct FileID) AS Total, Groups,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Success' AND Date = '2020-05-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Success
        FROM Table
        group by Group
        order by Total DESC
```

And this is the outcome

```
Total   Group      Success
58      Group 5    110        The correct one for this is 55
32      Group 77   0          The correct one for this is 0 
32      Group 78   27         The correct one for this is 27
31      Group 99   9          The correct one for this is 3
29      Group 89   13         The correct one for this is 4
29      Group 34   15         The correct one for this is 4
```

Comment: Hi @KratosMafia, Please post some sample data and expected results. With the information provided its hard to comprehend "Failed" and "Success".

Comment: Sorry, so right now I'm searching for the groups with the most counts. Then I will would need to do where Column_Name = 'Success' and get that count from those top records and then get the same where Column_Name = 'Failed' and it should equal the total that I began with.

I will update

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which RDBMS you are using there are window functions in oracle,mssql,postgresql etc.(almost all of them) You can use one of this window functions `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(GROUP BY GROUP ORDER BY TOTAL DESC)` then with care write down some cases into your select like  below.

```
CASE WHEN ... 'SUCCESS' THEN ROW_NUMBER()OVER(GROUP BY GROUP ORDER BY TOTAL DESC)
WHEN ...'FAIL' THEN
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(GROUP BY GROUP ORDER BY TOTAL ASC) END
```